# Splitting long character arrays in code cosmetic reasons

Tags: java

I am currently trying to write code that has a long character array. A requirement is that code should be at most 100 characters long.

For simplicity and readability in this question this requirement is 60 characters

e.g. The would fail

```
         1        2        3        4        5        6        7
0123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890

private static String s= "dghjkfkfdhkhkjhdfkjhfdkjhdfdfdfddfdfkhd";
```

One solution is to use the `+` operator i.e.

```
         1        2        3        4        5        6        7
0123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890123467890

private static String s = "dghjkfkfdhkhkjhdf" +
                   "kjhfdkjhdfdfdfddfdfkhd";
```

My gut feeling is that the operator will be executed at run time. Is this true and if so what overheads are incurred?

**OR**

Is there an alternative mechanism as in C where you can do?

```
 char s[] = "fjhdfdkjhfk"
            "kjfdhfkjdhkh";
```

This mechanism does not appear to work in Java

Comment: What is the type of `s`? Is is a string or char array?

Comment: Actually, Java should try to resolve concatentations at compiler time if possible, as far as I know.

Comment: @MAnouti - Oops - editied question

Comment: Jems is right, if you concatenate string literals, this will be done at compile time. So this has no runtime overhead.

Comment: Every `static` field gets initialized before starting `main` and the concatenation would happen during compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a string literal is not a character array in Java as it is in C, so your code doesn't compile because you can't assign a `String` object to a variable of type `char[]`. Fixing that by making the variable a `String`, then:

When you concatenate string literals with `+`, the Java compiler is smart enough to do the concatenation at compile time. So whether you break the string literal and concatenate the parts, or keep it as a single string literal, does not matter for the compiled code - the compiled code will be exactly the same.

You can verify this with the `javap` command. Compile your example class, and then use `javap` on it. For example: `javap -v Example` (if your class is named `Example`). You'll see the string literal in the output as one of the values in the constant pool:

```
Constant pool:
    ...
    #5 = String             #25            // dghjkfkfdhkhkjhdfkjhfdkjhdfdfdfddfdfkhd
```

Now change your code to concatenating two string literals, recompile and run `javap` again. You'll see that the constant pool still contains a single string literal.

You can also use the `-c` flag with `javap` to decompile your code; you'll see that there is no difference in the byte code, there will be no string concatenation done at runtime.

Comment: My mistake - fixed the question